# Scala 2.13: return same collection type (even Array and String)

Tags: scala, generics, scala-collections

Here's a basic implementation of a [faro shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faro_shuffle). This is an out-shuffle ("faro out, man!") just because it's a bit easier to code than an in-shuffle.

```
def faroOut[A](cards: List[A]): List[A] =
  List.unfold(cards.splitAt((cards.size + 1) / 2)) {
    case (a,b) => Option.when(a.nonEmpty)(a.head -> (b, a.tail))
  }

faroOut(List("AS","KD","QC","JH","2S","3D","4C","5H"))
//res0: List[String] = List(AS, 2S, KD, 3D, QC, 4C, JH, 5H)
faroOut(List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7))
//res1: List[Int] = List(1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7, 4)
```

This is generic on its element type but not on its collection type. Let's try to fix that.

```
import scala.collection.Factory

def faroOut[A, CC[x] <: Iterable[x]](cards:CC[A]
                                    )(implicit fac: Factory[A,CC[A]]
                                     ): CC[A] =
  Iterator.unfold(cards.splitAt((cards.size + 1) / 2)) {
    case (a, b) => Option.when(a.nonEmpty)(a.head -> (b, a.tail))
  }.to(fac)

faroOut(LazyList("AS","KD","QC","JH","2S","3D","4C","5H"))
faroOut(Vector(1,2,3,4,5,6,7))
//faroOut(Array(3,4,5,6))  <-- won't compile
```

Transitioning this to an extension method isn't too complicated, but that needn't concern us here.

So this works for Lists and Vectors but not for an `Array` or `String` because those come from Java-land and aren't part of the Scala `Iterable` hierarchy. For that we need to bring on the `IsSeq` type class.

Interestingly, that's pretty straight forward in Scala-3.

```
import scala.collection.generic.IsSeq
import scala.collection.Factory

def faroOut[Repr](cards: Repr
                 )(using seq: IsSeq[Repr]
                       , fac: Factory[seq.A,Repr]): Repr =
  val seqOps = seq(cards).toIterable
  Iterator.unfold(seqOps.splitAt((seqOps.size + 1) / 2)) {
    case (a, b) => Option.when(a.nonEmpty)(a.head -> (b, a.tail))
  }.to(fac)
```

And here's a [Scastie to prove it](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/sG1lVNlUQtKSBEnIeeevuA).

Transitioning this to an extension method is almost trivial, but that needn't concern us here.

Notice how the first type parameter for `Factory[_,_]` is dependent on the previous argument in the parameter group. A cool Scala-3 enhancement not possible on Scala-2.

After spending some time with the [Scala docs page](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/custom-collection-operations.html), and [this SO Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56542335/adding-custom-collection-operations-in-scala-2-13-to-arbitrary-collections-of-sp), I'm left with the **QUESTION** <sub>([at long last](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9463hBWy0ig))</sub>: Isn't there a smaller and/or simpler solution? Are we *really* required to turn it into an extension method with all the `implicit` conversions and such?

Comment: in your example, what do you mean by "extension method" and "implicit conversions" ?

Comment: 1 - I'm not interested in converting it to `List(...).faroOut`.  2 - The `implicit def ...` code as outlined in the links provided.

Comment: the other SO question explicitly asked for extension method in their code example. There is no other way in Scala to add method into a class that we don't own.

However if you don't care about the syntax, you can just call `faroOut(yourCollection)` as long as you have the factory in scope like what you already did. So not sure what was the question

Comment: Reread the question. I _don't_ want to add a method to any class. I _want_ `faroOut(myArray)` and `faroOut("myString")`. I can do it with Scala-3 but it doesn't appear possible with Scala 2.13.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get around Scala 2 dependent types within single parameter list limitation, try with type refinement

```
IsIterable[Repr] { type A = E }
```

or [Aux](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/9223/files) type alias pattern

```
type AuxA[Repr, E] = IsIterable[Repr] { type A = E }
```

For example

```
def faroOut[Repr, E](cards: Repr)(
  implicit 
  seq: IsIterable[Repr] { type A = E }, 
  fac: Factory[E, Repr]
): Repr = {
  val seqOps = seq(cards).toIterable
  Iterator.unfold(seqOps.splitAt((seqOps.size + 1) / 2)) {
    case (a, b) => Option.when(a.nonEmpty)(a.head -> (b, a.tail))
  }.to(fac)
}

faroOut(Array(3,4,5,6)) // : Array[Int] = Array(3, 5, 4, 6)
faroOut("ABCxyz")       // : String = AxByCz
```

[scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/yIehqqQhSiKQl6jI7wcYkA)

Comment: Mario. I was working on the string problem when you snuck your update in. Good work and many thanks. I would not have guessed that the element type could be represented both on its own, `E`, and at the same time as part of the `Repr`, or that the inference engine could determine the meaning of `E` from such references in the 2nd (implicit) parameter group. Some impressive smarts in that compiler.