# How to make a function working with different collection type in Scala 2.13?

Tags: scala, collections, scala-2.13

Following function accepted more or less any collection and returned it filtered:

```
def filterEven[Repr](o: collection.IterableLike[Int, Repr]): Repr = {
  o.filter { o =>
    (o % 2) == 0
  }
}

filterEven(List(1, 2, 3))

filterEven(Set(1, 2, 3))
```

How do I achieve the same with Scala 2.13? `IterableLike` no longer exists there. Should I use higher kinded types somehow?

Comment: You need the `IsIterable` **typeclass**: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/WOZyDmpDRu220lyISSJG8Q/2 - This is probably a duplicate I am too lazy to search.

Answer (score 3):

It seems higher kinded types together with `IterableOps` can be used to achieve this:

```
def filterEven[CC[Int] <: IterableOps[Int, CC, CC[Int]]](o: CC[Int]): CC[Int] = {
  o.filter { o =>
    (o % 2) == 0
  }
}
```

I found this more logical than the previous `Repr` based solution.

Inspired by [Adding custom collection operations in scala 2.13 to arbitrary collections of specific types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56542335/adding-custom-collection-operations-in-scala-2-13-to-arbitrary-collections-of-sp)

Comment: That won't let you use types like `BitSet`, not sure if that is ok or not for your use case.

Comment: My Scala 2.12 was for Iterables only as well, therefore it is OK for my use (I need List and Set). Your `IsIterable` solution looks nice as well. It feels a bit strange `BitSet` has `IsIterable`, but `IterableOps` do not accept it.

Comment: Yeah, the whole stdlib collections hierarchy is weird, I gave up on trying to understand it years ago; I just use **cats** typeclasses when it makes sense and a couple of `IsIterableOnce` to accept anything.

Comment: You can still use `IterableOps` for stuff like BitSet with two type parameters: `def filterEven[CC[_], C](col: IterableOps[Int, CC, C]): C`. It will convert Array to ArraySeq though since Array doesn't extend IterableOps